Expectation of $\mathbb{E}[\sum \delta_i / \sum T_i ]$
Let $T = \min\{X,C\}$, where $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $C \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\theta)$, $X$ and $C$ independent. Let $\delta$ be a random variable such that $\delta = 1$ if $X \leq C$ and $\delta = 0$ otherwise.
I would like to compute the expectation of $\mathbb{E} \left[ \dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \delta_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} T_i} \right]$. I have already proved that $T$ and $\delta$ are independent, and I know that $P(\delta = 1) = \lambda/(\lambda + \theta)$ and that the pdf of $T$ is given by $f_T = (\lambda + \theta) e^{-(\lambda + \theta) t}$.
I believe that the expectation of $ \hat \lambda = \dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \delta_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} T_i}$ is finite, so I tried
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{E} \, [ \hat \lambda ] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \delta_i \right] \cdot \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{1}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} T_i} \right]
\end{equation*}
However I am uncertain on how to compute the expectation of $1/\sum_{i = 1}^{n} T_i$. If anyone could give me a tip I would be very grateful.

$T_i \sim Exp(\lambda + \theta)$, then $T^* = \sum_i ^nT_i \sim Gamma(n, \lambda + \theta)$. You only have to compute $\mathbb{E}(1/T^*)$

You can use the following useful result [1] for $a=n$, $b=\lambda+\theta$, and $r=-1$ :

$$\mathbb E (X^{r})=\frac{\Gamma(r+a)}{b^r\Gamma(a)}$$ for $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b) $ and $r>-a$

to compute the expectation of $1/\sum_{i = 1}^{n} T_i$, by considering the point also mentioned by @Daniel $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} T_i \sim \text{Gamma}(n, \lambda+\theta).$$
See here for a simpler method.
